# Wordpress ftp_nb_fput missing - BackWPup

Tags: wordpress, web

I've set up a new Wordpress blog and already customized its look and fell. Everything went smooth up to know.
I just wanted to set up a backup plugin called BackWPup for a daily backup. I need to upload the backup files fia FTP to a designated server. When I create a new backup job I can't tick the storage location FTP cause the error "Missing function „ftp_nb_fput“" appears.

How can I fix that? Is it just a function which is disabled or is my wordpress version missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`ftp_nb_fput` is a regular PHP function which should be available to you no matter which PHP version you have on your hosting.

Therefore you probably need to contact your web hosting company and learn if they did not disable those functions on purpose (for example on a security basis).

Alternatively you website may be running on HHVM which lacks those functions but I doubt that this is the case.